# Siliconization for Organic Compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, home-experiment

I was wondering if it was possible to create Silane from Methane using the process of siliconization to replace the Carbon with Silicon. For example Silicon Carbide is produced by replacing C-C bonds with a Si-C bond.

Comment: What do you mean by siliconization and what is replacing bonds? In drawing, or in actual chemical reaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A key difference between carbon and silicon (and why you usually can't make an all-silicon version of an organic compound where all its carbons are replaced with silicon) is that long chains of silicon atoms are not stable. Another key difference is that a hydrogen attached directly to silicon, as in silane, is typically more reactive--say toward hydrolysis or oxidation--that one attached to a carbon atom. I do not know of any process to directly "silanize" a carbon compound, as stated in your question.